# Add labels to navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I am adding a calendar to my app and thought it would be cool to mimic the format of standard iOS Calendar app as per weekday labels:

[image]

In the Calendar app, these labels (S,M,T,W,T,F,S) seem to be integrated into the navigation bar, so I was wondering if there is a way to implement this or if this is something Apple left to themselves (as there seems to be no standard way to add anything but bar button items). Mind you, these labels should be dynamic - e.g. rearrange in case of day 2 as `firstWeekDay` for certain `Locale`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple proposes not to resize navigationBar itself, but remove shadow from bar and add custom view under your navigationBar.

Please refer the apple recommended approach for extended navigation bars here - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

And your particular scenario - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/NavBar/Listings/NavBar_ExtendedNavBar_ExtendedNavBarViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418-NavBar_ExtendedNavBar_ExtendedNavBarViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_13

Comment: Wow, thanks for the links - I somehow didn't come upon these in my search.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set a view to your title view of navigationItem for example:

```
sampleLabel.textAlignment = .center
sampleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
sampleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .medium)
sampleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 30)
sampleLabel.text = "T"
let titleView = UIView
titleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)
titleView.addSubview(sampleLabel)
navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```

You can add labels to your navigationBar like sampleLabel wherever you want.

Comment: A nav bar's `titleView` will be centered between the left and right nav bar items. It can't be used to add a view below the nav bar.

Comment: yes, this code just substitutes the title with provided labels - centered vertically in the navbar